# android Fragment not attached to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to use getString for my viewpager tab titles so i can support multilanguages, but every time i use getString i get the error Fragment not attached to activity in the logs and the app Force Closes!

Here is my fragment code

```
public class RecipesFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence[] Titles = {(getResources().getString(R.string.invcraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.wbcraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.ovencraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.painttitle))};
int Numboftabs = 4;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_fragment, container, false);
    return v;


}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


}
```

}

Comment: use `getActivity()`. `getResources()` requires a context. intialize in `onActivityCreated`. and do post the activity code where you attach fragment to the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your variable `Titles` as `getResources` can be used after `onAttach` is called

try to initialize it in `onAttach` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Titles = {(getResources().getString(R.string.invcraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.wbcraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.ovencraftingcardtitle)), (getResources().getString(R.string.painttitle))};
}
```

Comment: This has been deprecated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `getResources()` actually calls `getActivity().getResources()` and you are using it in variable initiation (before being attached to the activity). Try setting up the titles variable right before you need to use it.

I would also avoid having variables start with an uppercase letter as this makes them seem as though they are classes.