# onAttach(Activity) deprecated: where I can check if the activity implements callback interface

Tags: android, android-fragments

Before API 23 I used Fragment's onAttach methods to get my listener instance, then the reference is cleaned inside onDetach. ex:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = null;
    try {
        mListener = (SellFragmentListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SellFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

Is it safe to do the same check inside onAttach(Context context) or is there a better way to get the holder activity instance?

Comment: `onActivityCreated` ?

Comment: I usually do this kind of thing on `onResume()`/`onPause()`, especially if the listener will do anything that affects the UI.

Comment: @tibo I think that onActivityCreated it's not called when a Fragment is added to an existing activity.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede that's an option too!

Comment: Yes, this is good question. It's mean that documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html is wrong or not actual

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check the source code:

```
/**
 * Called when a fragment is first attached to its context.
 * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will be called after this.
 */
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mCalled = true;
    final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
    if (hostActivity != null) {
        mCalled = false;
        onAttach(hostActivity);
    }
}

/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #onAttach(Context)} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

So the `onAttach(Activity activity)` is called by the `onAttach(Context context)` if there is a host activity. You can use the `onAttach(Activity activity)` safely.

Comment: mHost is not accessible from outside the package...So what then?

Answer (score 5):

As shown in Zsolt Mester's answer, `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated in favor of `onAttach(Context context)`. Thus, all you need to do is check to make sure the context is an activity.

In Android Studio if you go to **File > New > Fragment**, you can get the auto generated code that will contain the proper syntax.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate fragment layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- Since the parent Activity must implement our `OnFragmentInteractionListener` (the arbitrarily named interface), checking `(context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)` ensures that the context is actually the activity.
- Note that we are using the support library. Otherwise `onAttach(Context context)` wouldn't be called by pre API 23 versions of Android.

**See also**

- [Creating and Using Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)
- [Android Fragment onAttach() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated)

Answer (score 4):

Well, what is deprecated is `onAttach(Activity activity);` method, but the whole flow remains. so you may do nothing really as `onAttach(Activity activity);` is going to be still supported long enough.

Answer (score 3):

I never had to use `onAttach(Context context)` yet but I think your code is basically good. So here is my suggestion, using your code:

```
public void onAttach (Context context) {
   super.onAttach(context);
   try {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        mListener = (SellFragmentListener) activity;
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SellFragmentListener");
    }
}
```

The main difference is that I can typecast `context` to get the Activity. This is because Context can propagate to the subclass which is the activity.

Another issue, API 23 is still far away from now for us to worry. If you do worry, using build pragma (static Build) may be a good option.

Comment: You should cast context directly. Or if you want the context to be an instance of an activity. Check that first by using if(context instanceof Activity) { ... }

Comment: @Daverix, Interesting comment "You should cast context directly". Please be more specific. Are you saying object context can/should be cast to mListener directly? That will reduce code from 2 lines to only 1 line. If so, that is a coding style difference only.

Comment: Yes, that may be a coding style difference, but still an unecessary line imo. Otherwise it's better to use  "instanceof" instead of catching ClassCastExceptions. But in the end maybe that only saves you a bit more lines and gain minimum performance.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same situation. I have gone through various posts and finally implemented my code in onCreate() block of fragment.Till now i haven't faced any issue and i think it wouldn't be an issue as onCreate is called immediately after onAttach in lifecycle.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            listnener = (TilesOnClickListnener)getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, i forgot to mention that casting context to Activity didn't work out well for me.

Comment: Why would Activity casting not work out well? Works fine for me, if you declare activity outside the try / catch block --- public void onAttach (Context context) { super.onAttach(context); Activity activity = (Activity) context; try { mListener = (SellFragmentListener) activity; } catch (ClassCastException e) { throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement SellFragmentListener"); } }

Comment: Great! if it is working. I haven't tried that.Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I use the native [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) rather than the [one from the Support Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html). I put both `onAttach()` methods in my code and did some debugging on devices running different SDK versions. I found that:

**SDK 22 and below** - only `onAttach(Activity)` is called. Not surprising really because [`onAttach(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) was only introduced in SDK 23.

**SDK 23 and above** - `onAttach(Context)` is called first *and then* `onAttach(Activity)`. (This is consistent with what @Zsolt Mester said about the source code in another answer to this post.)

Since `minSdkVersion` for my app was below 23 I just decided to omit `onAttach(Context)` altogether and simply add the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation to my existing `onAttach(Activity)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  topsection.TopSectionListener {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }



 public void createMeme(String top, String bottom){
    bottomsection fragmentbottom = (bottomsection) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    fragmentbottom.setMemeText(top, bottom);
  }
 }
```