# Method onAttach(Activity) deprecated having trouble implementing onAttach(Context)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Since `onAttach(Activity)` has been deprecated i have trouble running this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == loginButton){
        application.getAuth().getUser().setIsLogedIn(true);
        callbacks.onLoggedIn();
    }
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    callbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

public interface Callbacks{
    void onLoggedIn();
}
```

Now I get the `java.lang.NullPointerException` because  `callbacks.onLoggedIn()` returns `null`

I tried also:

```
  public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);
        callbacks = (Callbacks) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258125/onattachactivity-deprecated-where-i-can-check-if-the-activity-implements-call) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated) you can find well-reasoned discussion about your question. These posts will be helpful for better understanding of this issue.

And here are just few tips to let you quickly move on:

1) In your case you can use `context` as well as `activity`:

```
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof Callbacks){
        callbacks = (Callbacks) context;
    }
}
```

2) After your fragment is attached you can always get parent activity with `getActivity()` method