# Crash when on click button

Tags: android, kotlin

The folllowing is the error:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myhouse.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.myhouse.TasklistFragment$Callbacks at com.example.myhouse.TasklistFragment.onAttach(TasklistFragment.kt:50)

Where the code for tasklist at line 50 is

```
  interface Callbacks{
        fun addTaskToViewModel(task: Task, destinationTasklistType: Int)
        fun deleteTaskFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int, adapterPosition: Int)
        fun getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int) : LinkedList<Task>
    }

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as Callbacks?
    }
```

Comment: so passed `context` isn't an instance of (probably interface) `Callbacks`. its not a bug, it's a wrong design of app (assuming that `context` passed to `Fragment`s `onAttach` method will be always same as probably hosting `Activity`)

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258125/onattachactivity-deprecated-where-i-can-check-if-the-activity-implements-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use safe casting to avoid class cast exception which is causing the crash in this case. Like this

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as? Callbacks?
    }
```

Other than this, the context you are passing is not of type Callbacks which is causing the casting to fail. Maybe provide some more info to solve this issue.

Comment: it now gives an error on this line

Comment: private fun updateInterface(){
        val tasks = callbacks!!.getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType)
        adapter = TaskViewAdapter(tasks)
        taskRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myhouse.TasklistFragment.updateInterface(TasklistFragment.kt:12

Comment: added the interface as well