# passing images from fragment to activity - gettin null object

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, null

I have a `fragment` that captures 4 images, i want to pass them an `activity`, But I keep getting null object. I cant figure out what to do.

This is my fragment:

```
    public class RegFragFour extends Fragment {

    Uri imageCaptureUri;
    ImageView imgCbOne, imgCbTwo, imgCbThree, imgCbFour;
    Button btnCbChooseOne, btnCbChooseTwo, btnCbChooseThree, btnCbChooseFour, btnCbContinueToFour;
    static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 2;
    int pressedButton = 0;
    String passedPathOne, passedPathTwo, passedPathThree, passedPathFour;
    onDataPassFour dataPasser;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_four, container, false);

        imgCbOne = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgOne);
        imgCbTwo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTwo);
        imgCbThree = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgThree);
        imgCbFour = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFour);
        btnCbChooseOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChooseOne);
        btnCbChooseTwo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChooseTwo);
        btnCbChooseThree = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChooseThree);
        btnCbChooseFour = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChooseFour);
        btnCbContinueToFour = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnContinueToFour);

        btnCbChooseTwo.setEnabled(false);
        btnCbChooseThree.setEnabled(false);
        btnCbChooseFour.setEnabled(false);

        final String[] items = new String[]{"From Camera", "From Phone Memory"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    try {
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageCaptureUri);
                        intent.putExtra("return data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        btnCbChooseOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pressedButton = 1;
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnCbChooseTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pressedButton = 2;
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnCbChooseThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pressedButton = 3;
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnCbChooseFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pressedButton = 4;
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        btnCbContinueToFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Login = new Intent(getActivity(), FakeWelcome.class);
                startActivity(Login);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String path = "";
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            imageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(imageCaptureUri);
            if (path == null)
                path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
            if (path != null)
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        } else {
            path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }
        switch (pressedButton){
            case 1:
                imgCbOne.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                btnCbChooseTwo.setEnabled(true);
                passedPathOne = imageCaptureUri.getPath();;
                break;
            case 2:
                imgCbTwo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                btnCbChooseThree.setEnabled(true);
                passedPathTwo = imageCaptureUri.getPath();;
                break;
            case 3:
                imgCbThree.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                btnCbChooseFour.setEnabled(true);
                passedPathThree = imageCaptureUri.getPath();;
                break;
            case 4:
                imgCbFour.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                passedPathFour = imageCaptureUri.getPath();;
                break;
        }
        dataPasser.dataInfoRegFour(passedPathOne, passedPathTwo, passedPathThree, passedPathFour);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            dataPasser = (onDataPassFour) context;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface onDataPassFour {
        void dataInfoRegFour(String imgPathOne, String imgPathTwo, String imgPathThree, String imgPathFour);
    }
}
```

And this is my activity:

```
    public class FakeWelcome extends AppCompatActivity implements RegFragFour.onDataPassFour {
    ImageView imgCbOne, imgCbTwo, imgCbThree, imgCbFour;
    Button btnCbChooseOne, btnChooseTwo, btnChooseThree, btnChooseFour;
    String _imgPathOne, _imgPathTwo, _imgPathThree, _imgPathFour;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fake_welcome);
        imgCbOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgOne);
        imgCbTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTwo);
        imgCbThree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgThree);
        imgCbFour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFour);
        btnCbChooseOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseOne);
        btnChooseTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseTwo);
        btnChooseThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseThree);
        btnChooseFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseFour);

        btnCbChooseOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imgPathOne);
                imgCbOne.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
        btnChooseTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imgPathTwo);
                imgCbTwo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
        btnChooseThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imgPathThree);
                imgCbThree.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
        btnChooseFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imgPathFour);
                imgCbFour.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void dataInfoRegFour(String imgPathOne, String imgPathTwo, String imgPathThree, String imgPathFour) {
        _imgPathOne = imgPathOne;
        _imgPathTwo = imgPathTwo;
        _imgPathThree = imgPathThree;
        _imgPathFour = imgPathFour;
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.shaka.myparselogin.RegistrationFragments.RegFragFour$onDataPassFour.dataInfoRegFour(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.shaka.myparselogin.RegistrationFragments.RegFragFour.onActivityResult(RegFragFour.java:168)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
```

it points to this line:

```
dataPasser.dataInfoRegFour(passedPathOne, passedPathTwo, passedPathThree, passedPathFour);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, obviously the `dataPasser` object is null. In the code snippets shown it's only given a value in the `Fragments`'s `onAttach()` method. So you could place a breakpoint in `onAttach()`, debug your application and confirm that it's actually never called.

As for why it's not called: You seem to be using some version of an AppCompat library. There are e.g. these two discussions on StackOverflow covering the fact that the `onAttach()` method signature has changed from `onAttach(Activity)` to `onAttach(Context)`:

[onAttach() not called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604552/onattach-not-called-in-fragment)

[Android Fragment onAttach() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)

So probably the problem is that you have implemented the one that takes a `Context` as a parameter and your `Activity` tries to call the one that takes an `Activity` as a parameter.

You could check out e.g. those two links and probably you'll just need to change your `onAttach()` method signature accordingly.

The code change:

From...

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        dataPasser = (onDataPassFour) context;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...to...

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        dataPasser = (onDataPassFour) activity;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm new to android so its hard for me to do what you said. can you try to help me with the code?