# Android Fragments Communication

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a simple communication between 2 Fragments in an Activity. The first fragment has a button that when pressed is supposed to send the current time in milliseconds to the second fragment. The second fragment displays this at a Textview. Well I just don't what I am doing wrong.
Java and XML files are the following

```
package com.example.android.rssreader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RssfeedActivity extends Activity implements MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssfeed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
        DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        fragment.setText(link);
    }

}
```

activity_rssfeed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssreader.MyListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_rsslist_overview">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssreader.DetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_rssitem_detail">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailFragment

```
package com.example.android.rssreader;

/**
 * Created  on 9/19/2016.
 */
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_URL ="url";

    View view;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
                container, false);
        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String link = bundle.getString("url");
            setText(link);
        }
    }

    public void setText(String url) {

        txt.setText(url);
    }
}
```

fragment_rssitem_detail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="@string/default_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyListFragment

```
package com.example.android.rssreader;

/**
 * Created  on 9/19/2016.
 */
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,
                container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDetail("fake");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onRssItemSelected(String link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    // triggers update of the details fragment
    public void updateDetail(String uri) {
        // create fake data
        String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // send data to activity
        listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
    }
}
```

fragment_rsslist_overview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press to update"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for in suggestion!

The Stack Trace

```
09/21 21:59:32: Launching app
$ adb push E:\AndroidProjects\VogellaTut\RSSReader\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.rssreader
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.rssreader"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.rssreader
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.rssreader/com.example.android.rssreader.RssfeedActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.android.rssreader.test | com.example.android.rssreader
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.android.rssreader.test | com.example.android.rssreader
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.android.rssreader.test | com.example.android.rssreader
Connecting to com.example.android.rssreader
E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.android.rssreader is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8605', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1453)
V/ActivityThread: Class path: /data/app/com.example.android.rssreader-1.apk, JNI path: /data/data/com.example.android.rssreader/lib
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 258: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 261: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.android.rssreader, real application class is null.
W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1885 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1885 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 310: Landroid/app/Fragment;.onAttach (Landroid/content/Context;)V
I/Adreno200-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3050818)
                 Build Date: 01/18/13 Fri
                 Local Branch: lge_changes
                 Remote Branch: 
                 Local Patches: 
                 Reconstruct Branch: 
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d8d438)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.android.rssreader.MyListFragment.updateDetail(MyListFragment.java:53)
                      at com.example.android.rssreader.MyListFragment$1.onClick(MyListFragment.java:27)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8605', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: What is happening currently? Are you getting no behavior is it crashing?

Comment: The app runs and the fragments are displayed but when I press the button it crashess and a message is displayed at my phone saying the app has stopped

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error that appears in the log please add that to your question.

Comment: I added the stack trace. Do u have any clue about my app's problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using the wrong onAttach method so listener is null. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32678989/2478736

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)