# Layout inflater is null

Tags: java, android, adapter

Can someone help me? 
I don't know why have I javaNullExepction in LayoutInflater.Here is my code :

This code is in fragment :

```
ServiceManager.getInstance().getCampaign( new Callback <Campaign>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Campaign campaign, Response response) {
                campaigns = campaign;
                adapter = new RecyclerCampaignAdapter(getActivity(), campaign);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).marginProvider(adapter).showLastDivider().build());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (progressBar.isShown()) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed" + retrofitError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

here is code in my adapter :

```
 public RecyclerCampaignAdapter (Activity activity, Campaign campaignList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.campaignList = campaignList;
        this.inflater= LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }
```

I think `getActivity() == null` I don't know how can I fix it.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:212)
>               at tr.org.yyd.yeryuzudoktorlari.adapter.RecyclerCampaignAdapter.(RecyclerCampaignAdapter.java:38)
>               at tr.org.yyd.yeryuzudoktorlari.fragment.CampaignFragment$1.success(CampaignFragment.java:69)
>               at tr.org.yyd.yeryuzudoktorlari.fragment.CampaignFragment$1.success(CampaignFragment.java:65)
>               at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**EDIT:**
I use replace method on frgment transaction when user clicks on an item from menu.So CampaignFragment works okey when the user clicks in first time but it crashes when user clicks again while it is still on.
If I change into another fragment and come back to CampaginFragment there is no crash.

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView.Adapter ?

Comment: try to use getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity and in adapter use Context instance instead of Activity

Comment: Yes I am using RecyclerView.Apadpter. I call Recyclervew.Adapter in Fragment.There is no command for getApplicationContext.

Comment: **1.** check `getActivity()` result, probably it's null
**2.** where do you call `ServiceManager.getInstance().getCampaign` ? In `onCreateView` etc ?

Comment: The Service Manager is for retrofit. It is singelton class. Service Manager was in onCreateView but there was the same error.Then I thing if I call the service manager in onActivityCreated , maybe it fixed but that was useless too. :)

Comment: use this one RecyclerCampaignAdapter (Context context, Campaign campaignList)

Comment: If you are using targetSdkVersion 23 and using the framework Fragment class (instead of the support lib Fragment class) then it may have to do with the deprecating of `onAttach(Activity)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated. Use the support lib's Fragments to work around that.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know what make I a mistake. I use the same adapter, which is name difficult.I haven't an error i this adapter. :(

Comment: Okey I will be look right now.Thank u.

Comment: I am using targetSdk 22. Android studio kidding with me :D

Comment: The answer is  :   if(getActivity() != null) {
                    adapter = new RecyclerCampaignAdapter(getActivity(), campaigns);
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).marginProvider(adapter).showLastDivider().build());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

Answer (score 0):

The answer just that.I don't know how that fix it but it worked.It's just a control.

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
    adapter = ....
```