# Android Fragment onAttach Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have problem on my on Attach its doing red line on him and writing me :

"overrides deprecated method in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' "

Please help me understand what i am doing wrong ?
ty you for all the helpers !!

```
package com.example.omermalka.memecreator;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    /**
     * Created by omermalka on 14/11/2015.
     */



    public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        private static EditText TopText;
        private static EditText BottomText;

        TopSectionListener acitivtyCommander;

        public interface TopSectionListener{
            public void createMime(String top , String Bottom);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try{
                acitivtyCommander = (TopSectionListener) activity;
            }catch (ClassCastException e){
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
            }
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);

            TopText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.TopTextInput);
            BottomText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.BottomTextInput);
            final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.BottomTextInput);

            button.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            buttonClicked(v);
                        }
                    }
            );



            return view;
    }


        public void buttonClicked(View v) {
            acitivtyCommander.createMime(TopText.getText().toString(),BottomText.getText().toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
```

to

```
public void onAttach(Context context)
```

**Final code:**

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
       acitivtyCommander = (TopSectionListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: i change it and now i have error on the activity on the attach

Comment: ty for all your helping !!

Comment: @MysticaL Why the app will crash if `super.onAttach(context);` is commented. How to decide whether call to super class lifecycle method(s) is required or not in case of fragments. In case of Activities, I know its a compulsion(else exception is thrown right)