# Current Fragment null after switching mode from FragmentStatePagerAdapter /Get Current Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have an issue when I came back after switching mode either dark/light mode, then the current fragment is null. I want to get back my current fragment (not new fragment) after switching mode/after recreating activity. I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I already tried with InstantiateItem method [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826327/13418167). But I found that the method creates a new fragment. And using [SetRetainInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166902/13418167) but, I think SetRetainInstance is not the best way. I already searching the information but, still don't get it. I am using GetItem to declare the fragment inside the adapter. Currently I have 3 tabs/ 3 fragments.

```
public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 1:
                if (fragment1 == null)
                {
                    fragment1 = new FragmentOne(_parentActivity);
                }
                else
                {
                    fragment1.RefreshPage();
                }
                return fragment1;

            case 2:
                if (fragment2 == null)
                {
                    fragment2 = new FragmentTwo(_parentActivity);
                }
                return fragment2;

            case 3:
                if (fragment3 == null)
                {
                    fragment3 = new FragmentThree(_parentActivity);
                }
                else
                {
                    fragment3.fragment3Adapter.UpdateData();
                }
                return fragment3;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unrecognized fragments!!!");
        }
    }
```

Then, in the Activity, I am using OnPageSelected(position) to get/know the selected tab/ clicked tab.

```
 public void OnPageSelected(int position)
    {
        if (position == 1)
        {
            fragmentAdapter.RefreshPage();
        }
        else if (position == 3)
        {
            fragmentAdapter.fragment3.UpdateData();
        }
    }
```

Nah, in the OnPageSelected, my Fragment3 is null but the adapter is not null(`fragmentAdapter.fragment3.UpdateData();`). And FYI, I dont use FragmentTransaction to switch/get my fragments. So, is there a way to get current fragment without create a new fragment? Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cause of using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

It's inherited from the `PagerAdapter`,This `PagerAdapter` implementation will keep only the current page, and when the page is out of sight, it will be removed, freeing up its resources.

If the you only requires a small number of fixed fragments, `FragmentPagerAdapter` is a safe and appropriate choice.

So you could try to change using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.