# Reference to elements of fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

It is possible to get reference to element(like button) defined in xml layout of fragment and use it in another activity?

I tried to do that but have null object reference.

fragment_date_picker.xml

```
<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"
    android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
btPickTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_pickTime);
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    final DatePickerFragment dp=new DatePickerFragment();

    btOk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_ok);
    btOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(dp);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    btPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.ll_main
                    ,dp);
            ft.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you tried? Can you put some code?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can always inflate the view giving it the fragment's xml and then find that object in that view like `view.findViewById(R.id.myButton)` but I cannot see the point, why wouldn't you just do the things you need to do in your Fragment?

Comment: You should read the documentation on [communication between Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: I guess that you can only get some reference (not null) from layout you're using added with **setContentView()** at the currently activity, **UPDATED** I think that you can try with http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en Could it be?

Comment: Use a getter inside your `Fragment`, and communicate with the `Fragment` in the usual way: `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getButtonOrAnyOtherView()`

Comment: Yes i can use view.findViewById() in fragment class, but how i remove() the fragment from my activity when i press bt_ok? the reference to DatePickerFragment is in activity.

Comment: Ok - that isn't what your question asks, but now you've clarified I've answered with a few solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For removing a `Fragment`, via a button press inside said Fragment.

**Method One (Potentially the simplest)**

I haven't tested this, so it may not be possible...but you could try and access the `FragmentManager` from inside this fragment, and then have it remove itself. In this case, you would call this inside your `onClick()`. You may need to place `getActivity()` in front of `getFragmentManager()` here.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

**Method Two (Almost as simple, but bad practice)**

Place the above logic inside a public method in the `Activity` class your `Fragment` is attached to, and access it inside your `Fragment` `onClick()` like so:

```
((MyActivityName)getActivity()).nameOfPublicMethodToRemoveFragment();
```

**Method Three (Recommended way for a `Fragment` to Communicate with its `Activity`)**

Use an `interface` (Example pulled from [here](https://github.com/PPartisan/FragmentInterfaceExample)):

```
    public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private View rootView;
    private Button button;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static BlankFragment newInstance() {
        return new BlankFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction();
    }

}
```

*Main Activity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) == null) {
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, BlankFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction() {
        //Remove Fragment Here
    }
}
```

**Method Four (Alternative)**

Use an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to communicate from the Fragment to the Activity

Comment: What mean mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity; ? and why onAttach is deprecated when you use onAttach(Activity activity) ?

Comment: @PavelPalei You may want to use `public void onAttach(Context context)` instead of `public void onAttach(Activity activity)`. There's more on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated)