# Why is the context null?

Tags: android, android-context

I'm trying to implement code that sends an SMS by using the default SMS application but I'm getting null context and I don't understand why.

I already tried with getBaseContext(), getContext(), getApplicationContext with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm testing this code on a Moto E5 Android 8.1 Go.

The code is inside of MainActivity.java

```
public void sendSMS(String msg)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // At least KitKat
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this); //<---Line 107 --- Need to change the build to API 19

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)// Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose
        // any app that support this intent.
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    else // For early versions, do what worked for you before.
    {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", SMSParameters.getTelefono(this));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",msg);
        startActivity(smsIntent);

    }
}
```

**Part of HomeFragment class**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final Button buttonAusente = view.findViewById(R.id.button_ausente);
    buttonAusente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String message = null;

                //enviarComando AUSENTE

                //Line 70 below
            message = MessageGenerator.getMessageAusente(_password, _id, SMSParameters.getSecuencia(getContext())); //<-- Line 70
            new MainActivity().sendSMS(message);

        }
    });

    final Button buttonDesactivar = view.findViewById(R.id.button_desactivar);
    buttonDesactivar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String message = null;
           //enviarComando DESACTIVAR
            message = MessageGenerator.getMessageDesactivar(_password, _id, SMSParameters.getSecuencia(getContext()));
            new MainActivity().sendSMS(message);

        }
    });

    final Button buttonPresente = view.findViewById(R.id.button_presente);
    buttonPresente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String message = null;

               // enviarComando PRESENTE
            message = MessageGenerator.getMessagePresente(_password, _id, SMSParameters.getSecuencia(getContext()));
            new MainActivity().sendSMS(message);
        }
    });

    final Button buttonPanico = view.findViewById(R.id.button_panico);
    buttonPanico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String message = null;

            //  enviarComando(Comandos.PANICO);
            message = MessageGenerator.getMessagePanico(_password, _id, SMSParameters.getSecuencia(getContext()));
            new MainActivity().sendSMS(message);

        }
    });

    setStatusIcon(getContext(), Comandos.AUSENTE, view);
    setStatusIcon(getContext(), Comandos.DESACTIVAR, view);
    setStatusIcon(getContext(), Comandos.PRESENTE, view);
    setStatusIcon(getContext(), Comandos.PANICO, view);

    saveViewStatus(view);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question - also, where is this code being called? Are we in an Activity, a Service..?

Comment: Maybe I understand wrong the error says "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference"

Comment: I don't see you calling `getApplicationContext()` in the snippet you provided. Can you update your question to provide the information I asked for?

Comment: I replaced by "this" with same result. Give me a minute please, I'm updating.

Comment: Where is this code being called?

Comment: I added the code from where is being called. Do I forgot to to add something?

Comment: You haven't added it - you have the method declaration for `sendSms()`, but where is it being called?

Comment: Could you post these lines of code please, `MainActivity.sendSMS(MainActivity.java:107)` and `HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:70)`

Comment: @PPartisan I think now is ready, please refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new MainActivity().sendSMS(message);` - This wont work. First, you do not instantiate Activities via their constructor, but with an `Intent`, and second, because you don't want to create a new activity, but access the Activity the Fragment is currently attached to.

In order to communicate with the host Activity from your Fragment, you can see my answer [here (see Methods 2 and 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358498/reference-to-elements-of-fragment-from-activity/36360141#36360141) and [this sample project](https://github.com/PPartisan/FragmentInterfaceExample). These techniques are also outlined in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

Comment: I do it that way because when I created the method inside the class HomeFragment I get an error about static method being called from non-static method, also getContext() in red and more errors. Now I will read your links.

Answer (score 0):

not having a using System.Configuration; will cause this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).