# Getting getActivity as null in Fragment when lunching Home Activity from Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, android-notifications

I have below code configure to generate notification :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        intent.putExtra("IsNotification",true);

        int mNotificationId= Pref.getValue(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID,1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,mNotificationId /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Bitmap mBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(mBitmap)
                .setContentTitle("App Notification").setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        mNotificationId++;

        Pref.setValue(this,Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID,mNotificationId);
```

Now in Manifest i have

```
<activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            />
```

Now in `OnCreate` and `onNewIntent` on both i am checking that it's bundle have some notification value

Like below code commit fragment from `OnCreate` or `onNewIntent` depend on Activity Instance :

```
private void initNotification(){

        if(mNotitficationFragment==null){

            mNotitficationFragment= NotitficationFragment.newInstance();
        }

        if(!mNotitficationFragment.isAdded()){

            mFragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_home_container,mNotitficationFragment).commit();

        }



    }
```

So now my issue is when `onCreateView` of NotificationFragment called it's giving `getActivity() as null .

**NOTE**

For Fragment i am using `support-v4:23.1.1` for Fragment .

Comment: What if you got context in `Frgament onAttach(...)`? As [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) post said

Comment: @MD i need to check that

Comment: @MD Also it's shown as deprecated for onAttach(Activity mActivity)

Comment: You have to wait for the fragment to be attached to the activity, do it in onAttach or later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the related processing on or after `onActivityCreated` or in `onAttach`. For the `onAttach` deprecated warning, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32088447/1086930).