# How to call member function of a class that extend DialogFragment in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have written custom **DatePickerDialog** which extends **DialogFragment** and implements `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                R.style.MyDialogTheme, this, year, month, day);
    return dpd;
  }

  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

  }

  // own  methods
  String getFormattedDate() {
  }
}
```

and  I call this fragment in my MainActivity.

```
public class Booking_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == imgView_from) {
      // Initialize a new date picker dialog fragment
      DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
      // Show the date picker dialog fragment
      dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

      // error 
      dFragment.getFormattedDate();
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because you try to accessing a not valid method from **DialogFragment**. You need to create DatePickerFragment with:

```
DatePickerFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
```

Or casting it:

```
DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
((DatePickerDialog)dFragment).getFormattedDate();
```

But ***the major flaw*** is, you try to accessing the `getFormattedDate() method` before the `dFragment` object has finish instantiated. Remember that `show()` is an asynchronous call.

So you need to inform the `Booking_activity` activity when the `dFragment` has finish instantiated. You can use an interface for it. Something like the following:

1. In your DatePickerFragment, add interface:

   ```
   public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

     private DatePickerListener mListener;

     public interface DatePickerListener {
       void onDialogFinishInitialized();
     }

     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
               R.style.MyDialogTheme, this, year, month, day);

       // you need to inform the activity when Dialog has finish
       // initialized.
       mListener.onDialogFinishInitialized();

       return dpd;
     }

     ...

     // Need to add the activity as the listener.
     @Override 
     public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
       // the listener interface. If not, it throws an exception
       try {
         mListener = (DatePickerListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement DatePickerListener");
       }
     }

     ...

   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface in your Activity and call the `getFormattedDate()` method:

   ```
   public class Booking_activity extends AppCompatActivity
   implements View.OnClickListener, DatePickerFragment.DatePickerListener {
     ...
     private DatePickerFragment dFragment;
     ...
     @Override
     public void onDialogFinishInitialized() {
       // You can call the method here now
       dFragment.getFormattedDate();
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a new date picker dialog fragment with:

```
DatePickerFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
```

Like in the following code:

```
public class Booking_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == imgView_from) {

      // Initialize a new date picker dialog fragment
      DatePickerFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment(); // Changed this

      // Show the date picker dialog fragment
      dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

      // error 
        dFragment.getFormattedDate();
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the member functions by simply casting the object like shown below

```
((DatePickerDialog)dFragment).getFormattedDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function getFormattedDate access mode to **public**  like below

```
  public String getFormattedDate() {
        }
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The selected solution works well, but I wanted to point out that the onAttach() function is deprecated. I found some solutions here: [Android Fragment onAttach() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated)

I think the most popular answer was this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = getActivity();
}
```

They are changing onAttach(Activity activity) to onAttach(Context context).