# Override deprecated method in android.support.v4.app.fragment

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        activitycomander = (TopSectionListener) activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the code of my java class linking with MainActivity.
There is issue with `onAttach` method in Android Studio. It shows as strike-through with the message:

> `onAttach` (`android.app.activity`) is deprecated:

I'm also having a second issue in MainActivity:

```
 public void createMeme(String top, String bottom){
    bottomsection fragmentbottom = (bottomsection) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    fragmentbottom.setMemeText(top, bottom);
}
```

`topsection` and `bottomsection` are the names of my java classes, they are highlighted red with the message `cannot resolve method`.

I have done a clean rebuild on my project and checked the option to add or remove the imports automatically.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Fragment onAttach() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

First question regarding `onAttach` is a duplicate of [Android Fragment onAttach() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated)

Regarding `topsection` and `bottomsection`, Classes should **always** begin with a capital letter and use CamelCaps, as per the [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). So rename them to `TopSection` and `BottomSection`.

Also check if your class has been imported - if `bottomsection` is underlined then try **Alt+Enter** and select **Import Class**