# Why can't I override Fragment.onAttach(Context context)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

A member on my team generated stub fragments in Android Studio, and [`onAttach(Context context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) was automatically generated. However, the compiler reports the following errors in my code, shown below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}
```

1. `error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`
2. `error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity`

Why am I getting these error messages at compile time?

Comment: I wonder if this issue is related. What is the device api level you are compiling for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32083053/631051