# how to make sure getActivity() deoesn't return null?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to fragments and I'm trying to take an activity and convert it to a fragment. A lot of the stuff I'm using needs Context and when I use getActivity() I get a log of warnings that it may return null and I'm not sure how to fix it. I read that I should attach the fragment to the activity somehow, but I'm not sure. I'm basically using one activity and going to have 4 fragments because I want to use a navigation drawer.

This is in the main activity for showing the fragments

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_calendar:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new CalendarFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_survey:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SurveyFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_forum:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ForumFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            logout();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contact:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ContactFragment()).commit();
            break;
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And in the fragments onCreateView() I have this, I have a lot of methods and most of them use Context, I added the if statement because of the same warning and that seemed to work there but how should I take care of the rest on Context uses. I don't see making an if statement for each time a good thing.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

if (getActivity() != null) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.calendar);
}

AndroidThreeTen.init(getActivity());
initialBuild(view);
buildCalendarView();
setRecyclerView();


return view;
```

Edit

Related images

Also I tried without the `@NonNull`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/aklpz4/why_does_getactivity_in_fragment_might_be_null/.

You can use `onActivityCreated()` to access `getActivity()`, it won't be null. I usually use `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` to get `getActivity()`, but in some rare cases a fragment's *view* can be created *before* hosting activity when an application starts (but I don't remember this in real work).

In any case `getActivity()` is marked as `Nullable`, so you can compare it with `null` in any case.

UPDATE 1

See [getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function).

Between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` you can get `getActivity()`, so save context in `onAttach()` and later use it in `onCreateView()`.

UPDATE 2

Fragment:

```
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (context instanceof Activity){
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activity = null;
}

@Override
public void onCreateView() {
    // Use activity here.
}
```

UPDATE 3

Sorry,

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity){
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read about the `onAtttach()` but I don't know where that is supposed to go? or how to set that up

Comment: I get an error on `onAttach` saying overriding method should call super

Comment: @CoolMind have you worked with koin dependcy injection as well

Comment: @Nancy, do you use Dagger, Koin or Kodein?

Comment: @CoolMind no I don't

Comment: @sashabeliy, thanks for the hint, sorry, I tried it a bit 2 years ago, but forgot.

Comment: @Nancy, that's strange. Could you write a code with `onAttach()`? Do you extend `Fragment` or abstract class? Please, also attach a screenshot with the error. Or did you extend `Activity` instead of `Fragment`?

Comment: @Nancy please check instead fragment you can use https://github.com/dipenptl1/Navigation-Drawer-With-Multiple-Activity multiple activity good luck

Comment: @CoolMind I can but they code is slightly different than your suggestion, the `onAttach` and `super.onAttach` are both crossed out and the parameters say `@NonNull Activity activity`

Comment: @Nancy, did you insert a correct `onAttach`? There are 2: usual and deprecated. Usual is `public void onAttach(Context context)` and deprecated is `public void onAttach(Activity activity)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated.

Comment: @CoolMind I added some images of what is happening with the `onAttach()`

Comment: @CoolMind according to the link you provided the `super.onAttach()` should have `context` instead of `activity`

Comment: @Nancy, thanks! Sorry! I made a mistake. `super.onAttach(context);`.

Comment: @CoolMind Important thing is I'm no longer getting any warnings!